# How to put a uint8_t in a char array?

Tags: c++, types, casting, printf

I'm trying to send some data to a device using serial comunication:

```
void VcpBridge::write_speed(char address, int spd) {
    uint8_t speed = (uint8_t)(127);
    ROS_ERROR("VCP BRIDGE: Sending %u to %u", speed, address);
    char msg[8];
    char command = 0x55, size = 0x02, csum;
    csum = speed + 0x64 + address;
    sprintf(msg, "%c%c%c%c%c%c", command, address, speed, size, 0x64, csum);
    ROS_ERROR(msg);
    write(fd_, msg, 6);
}
```

`ROS_ERROR` here does the same as `printf`.

Everything works fine except when the value of `speed` is over 127. Then it always prints a `?` in it's position and the device doesn't recive the right info. Do you know any way to cast it correctly? I've tried `%u` but then the program crashes.

Comment: Are you trying to print `speed` as a `char`? What do you expect to get when it equals, say, `200`?

Comment: I presume you've stripped out some code for the sake of example, but in case you haven't, you do realize that you never put any values into `msg` before you `write()` it, don't you? Also, perhaps you should replace all the `char`s with `unsigned char`s (or `uint8_t`, which is typically just an alias for the same...).

Comment: @twalberg He did, with `sprintf(msg, ...);`

Comment: @EitanT Doh... my bad... I read `fprintf()`, not `sprintf()`.

Comment: In fact is not a matter o what I print, I only need the info to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good reason to use `sprintf` in your example. Try this:

```
void VcpBridge::write_speed(char address, int spd) {
    uint8_t speed = (uint8_t)(127);
    ROS_ERROR("VCP BRIDGE: Sending %u to %u", speed, address);
    char command = 0x55, size = 0x02, csum;
    csum = speed + 0x64 + address;
    ROS_ERROR(msg);
    char msg[] = { command, address, speed, size, 0x64, csum};
    write(fd_, msg, sizeof msg);
}
```

Comment: +1, but note all the mixing of types still going on (char, uint8_t, and--implicitly--int and unsigned int).  Implicit integral promotions were likely the cause of the problem in the original code.  To avoid future problems (like what happens if the csum value is truncated) I would write the code using one type, probably uint8_t, eliminate as many conversions as possible, and make the necessary ones explicit (with casts).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answer I could figure out hot to fix the problem. Not using sprintf and using unsigned int was the kay.There's the final code:

```
void VcpBridge::write_speed(char address,int spd){
  uint8_t speed = (uint8_t)(200);
  unsigned char command = 0x55, size=0x02, csum;
  csum=speed+0x64+address;
  unsigned char msg[8]= { command, address, speed, size, 0x64, csum };
  write( fd_, msg, 6);
}
```

Comment: It isn't vital, but you may give your array a dimension of `6`. You give it eight bytes but only use six of them.

Comment: That's true, I did that before knowing the message size.